# Making Histograms with GNUPlot

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I want to make two comparative histograms out of one data file, using columns 1,2 and 1,3.

(Data file name is 'Cumulos por Edades.tab')

```
6.25   46   60
6.75   29   65
7.25   79   70
7.75   87   75
8.25   80   80
8.75   41   84
9.25   28   89
9.75   13   94
```

I have been able to make something out, but is not what i want. Here is the code.

(Sorry I can't upload an image of the result)

```
set terminal postscript enhanced color dashed lw 2 "Helvetica" 14
set output "Histograma.ps"
set key horizontal below height 1
set key box lt 1 lc -1 lw 2
set xlabel "log(t)"
set ylabel "N(t)"
set xrange [6:10]
set xtics 6,0.5,10
set grid ytics ls 2 lc rgb "black"
set title "Histograma de Cumulos Abiertos por Edades"
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 1
plot "Cumulos por Edades.tab" u 1:2 w boxes lc rgb 'blue' t 'Generacion Real',\
"Cumulos por Edades.tab" u 1:3 w boxes lc rgb 'red' t 'Generacion Constante'
```

What I want to get is an histogram where I can see both columns, but all I can get is the superposition of one over the other.

I would really appreciate if any of you could give me a hand with this.

Answer (score 4):

Using `set style data histogram` is equivalent to using `with histogram`. You overwrite this with `with boxes`.

The easiest way is to plot as `histogram`. Here is a minimal, running script:

```
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 1
plot "Cumulos por Edades.tab" u 2, "" u 3
```

That shows, how histograms are plotted: The values in the first row are centered at `x=0`, the second at `x=1` and so on. Unfortunately, you can't use the first column as in any other plotting style as numeric `x`-value. But you could use the value 'as-is' using `xtic(1)`, which reads the value of the first column as string and uses it as tic label:

```
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 1
plot "Cumulos por Edades.tab" u 2:xtic(1), "" u 3
```

The second option is to use the `boxes` plotting style:

```
plot "Cumulos por Edades.tab" u 1:2 with boxes, "" u 1:3 with boxes
```

Here, both columns are plotted around the same `x`-value, and though overlap. So you need to shift one column a bit to the left and the other to the right. And you must set a fixed boxwidth:

```
set boxwidth 0.2 absolute
plot "Cumulos por Edades.tab" u ($1-0.1):2 with boxes,\
     "" u ($1+0.1):3 with boxes
```